# How to make a variable that can be modified and read from different structures

Tags: variables, swiftui

I have a variable that I need to be able to be able to access thats controlled through this structure

```
HStack {
  Button(action : {
    if (lane != 1) { lane -= 1 }
  }) {
    Rectangle()
      .frame(width: 200, height: 900)
      .opacity(0)
  }
                
  Button(action: {
    if (lane != 4) { lane += 1 }
  }) {
    Rectangle()
      .frame(width: 200, height: 900)
      .opacity(0)
  }
}
```

And I need to access the up to date lane variable in this area which is in a different structure

```
if(carLane == enemyLane && Enemy1OffsetY == 150) {
  fatalError()
}
```

The variables are defined as `@State public var` if that helps at all

Comment: Make the variables that you need access to owned by a common parent view and pass them via simple property or `Binding` if you need to mutate them.

Comment: I tried to give make the variable binding but that gave a bunch of errors including files that it needs to access not existing anymore and me not being completly sure how I would define the default value for it

Comment: You would need to show your code in order for us to debug that. You don't give a Binding a default value -- it inherits a value from the parent. At the parent level, it should be `@State`

Comment: @jnpdx sorry for the late reply but heres a link to the code https://github.com/SuperbiaR/Controller/tree/main/Controller%20Take%202 The lane value is controlled in the Content View File and its needing to be accessed in the enemies file

Answer (score 0):

If both structures are views, you can pass the variable from one structure to another structure by setting a binding variable in the second structure.

```
struct SecondStructView: View {
    @Binding var lane: Int
}
```

and call the second view like this

```
SecondStructView(lane: $lane)
```